# How to show PHP MySQL result under the correct column for a kanban board

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I am building a Trello style board with PHP and MySQL shown in the screenshot image below.

Each of my column/boards comes from a database record.

```
SELECT * FROM `order_status` ORDER BY `sort_order` ASC
```

With the result of my MySQL query from my `order_status` table, I will loop over it to create each Board/Column in the KanBan board.

I have a 2nd MySQL query that will get all m`cards` that will go on to the board columns.

My image below shows a board column for **Backlog** and **In-Progress** so when I get my card records, I need to print them out to screen under the correct board columns that match up with the board names.

The MySQL query to get my record might look like this...

```
SELECT * FROM `board_cards` ORDER BY `modified_date` ASC
```

So from my `board_cards` result there is a `board` column which will have a value that matches up with one of the board names.

How would I go about printing the cars under each board column?

**About how that might look (not real code)**

```
$boardColumnNames = 'SELECT * FROM `order_status` ORDER BY `sort_order` ASC'

while($boardColumnNames){

    // loop over each board column and print out all the board card records     that belong on each board column

}
```

Can someone help be with how that PHP might look considering I have the board names in a variable and the board cards in a variable and each board card has a board value that will tell which board it belongs under?

Would it be best to get all my board card records and loop over them, putting all cards for each board into it;s own array variable.  After that while looping over to build each board/column I could loop over the array that belongs to that board.

OR

Would it be better to instead use some sort of JOIN in my database result to do it all at once somehow?

[image]

Comment: From only what you currently posted it's very difficult to understand which fields from your queries should go to which columns of the resulting board. Moreover when you say "column" it's not obvious that you're talking about DB fields or board structure. So can you edit your question to more precisely explain all that?

Answer (score 0):

Add a board_column_id field in your cards table. This column references a board_columns table which holds all your columns. You want to query first all your column_boards, loop over them and query your cards table by column_id. Here's some pseudocode:

```
columns = "select * from column_boards order by column_order";
foreach(col in columns) {
   cards = "select * from cards where column_id=col.id";
   foreach(card in cards) {
       draw(card);
   }
}
```